# how to check if bash function exist on remote computer

Tags: linux

I read various answers on similar topic, but I still can't deal with my problem. Namely, on the remote computer I have a .bashrc file with a bunch of custom made functions. I would like to check if that function exists in that file. Just to add that the script constantly reports that there is a specified function on the remote computer even though it is not. This is what I have done so far:

```
echo "Enter IP addres of the remote PC [def host@XX.XX.XX.XX]"
read ip
ip=${ip:-host@XX.XX.XX.XX}
    
$(ssh $ip "[ '$(type -t $1)' = function ]")
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "function exist"
else
  echo 'function doesnt exist'
fi
```

Comment: Why not grep for the keyword you're searching for? If present, function exists.

Answer (score 1):

`$(...)`is expanded localy inside `"` quotes. Reseach difference between single and double quotes.

```
the_function_you_want_to_check=something
ssh "$ip" '[ "$(type -t "'$the_function_you_want_to_check'")" = function ]'
```

Do not use `$?`. Just:

```
if ssh stuff...; then
      echo yes
else
      echo no
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your prompt response. Please note that $1 is actually the first parameter of the bash functions that I run on my local computer. Now, the change you suggested reports that there is no function on the remote computer even though it exists. More complete function that I run  on the local machine is:

```
appendFunction_to_remotePC(){

  echo "Enter the IP addres of the PC [def host@XX.XX.XX.XX]"
  read ip
  ip=${ip:-host@XX.XX.XX.XX}

  if ssh "$ip" '[ "$(type -t "'$1'")" = function ]'; then
    echo yes
  else
    echo no
  fi
      
}
```

I call the function on the local computer in the usual way:

```
$ appendFunction_to_remotePC "test"
```