# How do I properly use SSH heredoc?

Tags: linux

This question is somewhat related to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361084/how-to-check-if-bash-function-exist-on-remote-computer), but it has not been adequately answered. What interests me here is the following:

When I run the command `type -t test` on a remote computer, I get the answer 'function' because the 'test' is an existing function inside the .bashrc file on the remote computer.

However, when I run this SSH command on the local computer,

```
s="$(
ssh -T $HOST <<'EOSSH'
VAR=$(type -f test)
echo $VAR
EOSSH
)"
echo $s
```

I don't get anything printed. The first question would be how do I make this work?

The second question builds on the previous one. That is, my ultimate goal is to define on a local computer which function I want to check on a remote computer and come up with an adequate answer, ie.:

```
a="test"
s="$(
ssh -T $HOST <<'EOSSH'
VAR=$(type -f $a)
echo $VAR
EOSSH
)"
echo $s
```

So, I would like the variable s to be equal to 'function'. How to do it?

Comment: `inside the .bashrc` So when do you think bashrc is getting loaded?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I make this work?

Either load `.bashrc` (`. .bashrc`) or start an interactive session (`bash -i`).

Because your work is not-interactive, if you want `.bashrc` loaded *and* it has no protection against non-interactive use, just load it. If not, maybe move your function somewhere else, to something you can source. If not, be prepared that interactive session may print /etc/motd and /etc/issue and other interactive stuff.

Remove `-T` - you do not need a tty for non-interactive work.

> I would like the variable s to be equal to 'function'. How to do it?

I recommend using `declare` to transfer all the work and context that you need, which is flexible and works generically, preserves STDIN and doesn't require you to deal with the intricacies escaping inside a here document. Specifically request `bash` shell from the remote and use `printf "%q"` to properly escape all the data.

```
functions_to_check=(a b c)
fn_exists()       { [[ "$(LC_ALL=C type -t -- "$1" 2>/dev/null)" = function ]]; }
work() {
   for f in "${functions_to_check[@]}"; do
         if fn_exists "$f"; then
            echo "Great - function $f exists!"
         else
            echo "Och nuu - no function $f!"
         fi
   done
}

ssh "$host" "$(printf "%q " bash -c "
$(declare -p function_to_check)  # transfer variables
$(declare -f fn_exists work)     # transfer functions
work                             # run the work to do
")"
```

Comment: for some reason what you suggested does not work I hope this is not a problem in running the shell script: I put the code you suggested in p.sh, change chmod so I can execute it and run like $ ./p.sh.

Comment: `functions_to_check` -> `function_to_check`. Add `set -x` to the script to debug it. Add `set -x` inside `bash -c "set -x ; ....` to debug the remote part. Or just `bash -xc "..."`. The code, as now, with `host=some_my_host` prints that there are no `a` `b` `c` functions.

Comment: I'm not at a high level of knowledge of Bash programming, so I do not read very well the debugging output. If you are willing to help me, I can send the result of debugging via Comment

Comment: for some reason it reports that it does not exist for all functions. For example, on a remote computer there is a function 'proba1' and the output is:  Och nuu - no function a!
Och nuu - no function b!
Och nuu - no function c!
Och nuu - no function proba1!